# Send Android Message with Firebase Cloud Messaging using FirebaseAdmin

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried for days to get FirebaseApp to send a message. Please someone tell me what is wrong here:

```
   FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
    {
        Credential =GoogleCredential.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Services\\Messaging\\MY_app-12345.json")).CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging")
    });



    public static async Task SendAsync(string deviceRegId, string message)
    {

    FirebaseMessaging fbMessage = FirebaseMessaging.GetMessaging(app);

        FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message m = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message
        {
            Token = deviceRegId,
            Android = new AndroidConfig()
            {
                Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                {
                    Body = message,
                    Title = "Title",
                    Sound = "bing"               
                },
                Priority = Priority.Normal,
            }
        };

            string response = await fbMessage.SendAsync(m);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
    }
```

Never gets past the fbMessage.SendAsyc and app never receives a message. No errors that I can see, just nothing happens. Thanks!